# SQL syntax error on PHP insert statement containing form _REQUEST

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I'm having a small issue with inserting data from a form into my database, the following INSERT statement:

```
        if (isset($_REQUEST['Submit'])) { 
        // Code to insert note into field;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO fields (notes) VALUES   
        ('".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['note']))."') 
        WHERE companyId='".$companyid['id']."' AND fileNumber ='".$filename."'";

        if($result = mysql_query($sql)) { 
        echo "<h1>Thank you</h1>Your information has been entered into our database<br><br>";
        } else { 
        echo "ERROR: ".mysql_error(); 
        } 
        } else {
```

Produces this error message:

```
        ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE companyId='11' AND fileNumber =''' at line 1
```

First and foremost the $filename variable obviously isn't showing up, I can copy the $companyid[id] var into the field and it display the var contents correctly but still throws up the syntax error.

I'm a PHP SQL noob and am teaching myself so please go gentle on me :)

Heres the full code minus the form

```
      <?php 
include "header.php";
$checkFiles = "checkFiles.php";
// Catches form input from previous page and stores it into session variable called filename for future reference;
$_SESSION['filename']=$_POST['filename'];
$filename = $_SESSION['filename'];
//User id stuff from previous page too; 
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$id = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE DXNumber='".$userid."'");
// Returns pointer so fetch it as an array and insert it into variable $companyid for later use;
$companyid = mysql_fetch_array($id);

if (isset($_REQUEST['Submit'])) { 
// Code to insert note into field;
$sql = "INSERT INTO fields (notes) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['note']))."') 
        WHERE companyId='".$companyid['id']."' AND fileNumber ='".$filename."'";
    if($result = mysql_query($sql)) { 
        echo "<h1>Thank you</h1>Your information has been entered into our database<br><br>";
        } else { 
        echo "ERROR: ".mysql_error(); 
        } 
        } else { 
        ?>
```

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason you should not be using `mysql_query` in new code. Although you've tried to escape values using `mysql_real_escape_string`, you've missed many instances where you have [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: Hi Tad, I realise thats the case, as I'm a bit green am focussing on getting the code working and then will go back over it to secure it. I just want to keep things simple for the moment, thanks for pointing it out though :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERT INTO` statements don't have `WHERE` clauses.

It should be `INSERT INTO <table> (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (value1, value2, value3)` 
and not `INSERT INTO <table> (field1) VALUES (value1) WHERE field2 = value2` etc.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html.

Comment: Thanks PD, thats all I needed to point me in the right direction. Back to the books it is :)